# Can not insert data into Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can not insert data into my database, i think i have some mistakes in my code, but i can not find it, can anyone show me my mistake.
I can add data when the `$mieuta ==""` but when `$mieuta !== ""` i can not insert it.

Here is my code:  please help me.

```
    if (isset($_POST["add"])) {

    $ten_sp = $_POST["ten_sp"];
    $ngay_sx= $_POST["ngay_sx"];
    $ma_sp = $_POST["ma_sp"];
    $vitrilapdat = $_POST["vitrilapdat"];
    $chungloai = $_POST["chungloai"];
    $nhom = $_POST["nhom"];
    $d_an = $_POST["d_an"];
    $nhasx = $_POST["nhasx"];
    $mieuta = $_POST["mieuta"];
    if ($ten_sp == "" || $ngay_sx == "" || $ma_sp == "" || $vitrilapdat =="" || $chungloai =="" || $nhom =="" || $d_an=="" || $nhasx =="") {
    echo '<h4 align=center style="color: red;">Vui lòng nhập đầy đủ thông tin</h4>';
    }else if($mieuta ==""){
    //thực hiện việc lưu trữ dữ liệu vào db
    $sql = "INSERT INTO products(
    ten_sp,
    ngay_sx,
    ma_sp,
    vitrilapdat,
    chungloai,
    nhom,
    d_an,
    nhasx
    ) VALUES (
    '$ten_sp',
    '$ngay_sx',
    '$ma_sp',
    '$vitrilapdat',
    '$chungloai',
    '$nhom',
    '$d_an',
    '$nhasx'
    )";
    // thực thi câu $sql với biến conn lấy từ file connection.php
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    header('Location:prod_management.php');
    }else if($mieuta!== ""){
        //thực hiện việc lưu trữ dữ liệu vào db
        $sql = "INSERT INTO products(
        ten_sp,
        ngay_sx,
        ma_sp,
        vitrilapdat,
        chungloai,
        nhom,
        d_an,
        nhasx,
        mieuta
        ) VALUES (
        '$ten_sp',
        '$ngay_sx',
        '$ma_sp',
        '$vitrilapdat',
        '$chungloai',
        '$nhom',
        '$d_an',
        '$nhasx',
        '$mieuta'
           )";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    header('Location:prod_management.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get? is there a mieuta field in your database table?

Comment: yes it's on my database, it has no errors but i can not see the value in the database when i finish it :(

Comment: echo `$sql` and run it in phpmyadmin

Comment: it will be ok if i leave the value $mieuta=="" and the value of $mieuta will be default, but if the $mieuta !=="" i will can not insert the value on database :(

Comment: If `mysqli_query` returns false, then the query has an error. You can get the error message by calling `mysqli_error` in the event of a false result. Additionally, you should be using prepared statements, as using values from post directly in SQL statements is considered insecure.

Comment: i run the sql on phpmyadmin it shows that i have an errors on the syntax, can you help me find it?

Comment: paste here what you get output of sql query

Comment: check your $_POST first are you getting any value in $_POST["mieuta"] or empty?

Comment: this is the thing i get:

Comment: There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: yep ofcourse i get the value in $_POST["mieuta"]

Comment: Whats the output of <?php echo $sql; die() ?>

Comment: i get nothing, just the sql that i've posted

Comment: There must be something inside the VALUES ('xyz','pqe'......) , show that output. Might be something inside your data is causing sql error

Comment: `else if($mieuta  != "")` replace it with your code and try it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `!==` Operator which means like that:

```
$x !== $y
```

Returns true if `$x` is not equal to `$y`, or they are not of the same type.

That means `$mieuta` is empty variable.

Comment: i know it, but even when i use else instead of else if($mieuta !== "")  i still can not insert the value, i think i have problem with syntax, can you help me find it. :(

Comment: @HoàngTrungHiếu: ist you check your $_POST array, and check what is the value of $mieuta?

Comment: @HoàngTrungHiếu: yes ofcourse. atleast check the $_POST

Comment: <tr><td>Miêu tả(Optional) : </td><td><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" style="width: 326px;" name="mieuta"></textarea></td></tr>

Comment: that is my html code, i mean i already define the value $mieuta here

Comment: but your textarea is empty @HoàngTrungHiếu

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
else if(empty($mieuta)){ # change. Check empty

    }
else if(!empty($mieuta)){ # Change. Check not empty

}
```

**EDIT 01**

Add

```
if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

---

```
if (isset($_POST["add"])) {

    $ten_sp = $_POST["ten_sp"];
    $ngay_sx= $_POST["ngay_sx"];
    $ma_sp = $_POST["ma_sp"];
    $vitrilapdat = $_POST["vitrilapdat"];
    $chungloai = $_POST["chungloai"];
    $nhom = $_POST["nhom"];
    $d_an = $_POST["d_an"];
    $nhasx = $_POST["nhasx"];
    $mieuta = $_POST["mieuta"];

    if ($ten_sp == "" || $ngay_sx == "" || $ma_sp == "" || $vitrilapdat =="" || $chungloai =="" || $nhom =="" || $d_an=="" || $nhasx =="") 
    {
    echo '<h4 align=center style="color: red;">Vui lòng nhập đầy đủ thông tin</h4>';
    }
    else if(empty($mieuta)){
        //thực hiện việc lưu trữ dữ liệu vào db
        $sql = "INSERT INTO products(ten_sp, ngay_sx, ma_sp, vitrilapdat, chungloai, nhom, d_an, nhasx ) VALUES (
        '$ten_sp','$ngay_sx','$ma_sp','$vitrilapdat','$chungloai','$nhom','$d_an','$nhasx')";
        // thực thi câu $sql với biến conn lấy từ file connection.php
        if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
            echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
        }

    }
    else if(!empty($mieuta)){
        //thực hiện việc lưu trữ dữ liệu vào db
        $sql = "INSERT INTO products(ten_sp,ngay_sx,ma_sp,vitrilapdat,chungloai,nhom,d_an,nhasx,mieuta) VALUES (
        '$ten_sp','$ngay_sx','$ma_sp','$vitrilapdat','$chungloai','$nhom','$d_an','$nhasx','$mieuta')";
        if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
            echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
        }
    }
    header('Location:prod_management.php');
}
```

Comment: what should be happened when you suppose $mieuta is not empty, is go to this check else if($mieuta =="")???

Comment: now if i leave value $mieuta =="" , i will can not insert the value.
But if the $mieuta is not empty so it will add to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by assigning a default value to `$mieuta`.

```
$mieuta = $_POST['mieuta'] || 'NULL';
```

Then, you just need one query and no `if` statements.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products(ten_sp,ngay_sx,ma_sp,vitrilapdat,chungloai,nhom,d_an,nhasx,mieuta) VALUES ('$ten_sp','$ngay_sx','$ma_sp','$vitrilapdat','$chungloai','$nhom','$d_an','$nhasx','$mieuta')";

if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}

header('Location: prod_management.php');
```